# Is the more general uncertainty principle related to bias-variance tradeoff?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, intuition, machine-learning, variance

Since I first saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4) on the more general uncertainty principle, I have taken the bias-variance tradeoff to be an example of it.  They seem quite similar on the surface.

However, now that I'm looking into the bias-variance tradeoff in detail, I'm not seeing anything obviously relate to Fourier Transforms.

Are bias and variance conjugate variables, or if not, is there any connection at all between the more general uncertainty principle and the bias-variance tradeoff?